# ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" not work in asp:GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

Why ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" not work in asp:GridView?, this is my code

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" RowStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle"  >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" HeaderText='<%$ Resources:Language, Admin_Employee_TimeTracker_GV_Code %>'>          
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox id="txtReferenceCode" runat="server" text='<%# Bind("referenceCode")%>' MaxLength="100" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate> 
            <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Middle" />  
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the page, right-click, and view source; it's probably adding the style to the wrong element.  I think it adds it to the row, which it's not setting correctly?  I've experienced something like that with the empty data template...

Take a look and see which underlying HTML element it applies it too first.

Answer (score 1):

You should use like this;

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" RowStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" CssClass="GridView1"  >
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" HeaderText='<%$ Resources:Language, Admin_Employee_TimeTracker_GV_Code %>'>          
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox id="txtReferenceCode" runat="server" text='<%# Bind("referenceCode")%>' MaxLength="100" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate> 
        <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Middle" />  
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

And Css part will be like this;

```
<style type="text/css">
    .GridView1 tbody tr th {
        vertical-align: central !important;
        text-align: center !important;
    }
</style>
```